# Python/scrapy - print objects with long strings

Tags: python, scrapy, pprint

Currently working with Scrapy and I'd like to see what I'm doing.
But it seems as if Scrapy or probably Python cuts off longer strings if I want to print an object:

```
    products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]')
    pprint ( products )
```

Now I receive:

```
<Selector xpath='//div[@class="s-item-container"]' data=u'<div class="s-item-container"><div class'>,
<Selector xpath='//div[@class="s-item-container"]' data=u'<div class="s-item-container"><div class'>,
<Selector xpath='//div[@class="s-item-container"]' data=u'<div class="s-item-container"><div class'>,
```

in my shell - how could I print everything that products contains? (the HTML content is chopped off).

With

```
print ( products)
```

I receive:
    `[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="s-item-container"]' data=u'<div class="s-[<item-container"><div class'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="s-item-container"]' data=u'<div class="s-item-container"><div class'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="s-item-container"]' data=u'<div class="s-item-container"><div class'>,`

Pretty much the same - just in a messy way.
So it's probably the fault of `Selector(response).xpath` to return a short version of my data?

Comment: It is definitely not a problem with Python, I just printed an object which returned a string of length 1000.

Comment: What do you get by a plain `print (products)`?

Comment: It is not a problem with `pprint` either.

Comment: That's surprising - so it might be scrapy specific. I added some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy Selector.xpath does not return strings. It returns list of selector objects. When you print selector you are printing string representaton of object. So you are calling Selector `__str__` method which as you can see in source code shows some selected attributes of object [1](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/selector/unified.py#L151) by default trimming html to first 40 chars.
To get list of strings you need to call `extract()`. So you need:

```
Selector(response).xpath("//text()").extract()
```

Also note that you dont need to convert response to selector. In recent Scrapy version `response.xpath` will also work.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the good explanation.
Now I get u'asfasfasfd' which - as I just figured out via the docs is a unicode string, but in MongoDB it's saved without the u, just as a string if I do: 
`Selector(response).xpath("//text()").extract()[0]`
So .. the first item of the list.